# What is the probability that you draw 2 cards and they sum 21?

Tags: probability, card-games

An ace is always worth 11, all face cards (Jack, Queen, King) are worth 10, and all number cards are worth the number they show. Given a shuffled deck of  52  cards **what is the probability that you draw 2 cards and they sum $21$**?

I have counted the number of possible hands $(52C2) = 1326$ and then the combination that adds to $21$ which is $10+11$, there are 16 cards of value 10: 4 10s, Js, Qs, Ks, and then 4 cards of value 11: 4 aces.

So the probability that the 2 drawn cards sum to $21$:

> $(16*4)/1326$

However, that is an incorrect answer...

Comment: Who says it's incorrect?

Comment: In $(52C2)$, you don't consider the order in which cards are drawn. In $(16 \cdot 4)$, however, you do.

Comment: @Dirk No, he doesn't. He just considers which ace can be drawn, and which 10 can be drawn. He does not consider which is drawn first, entirely in accordance ith using $52C2$ to count the total number of hands.

Comment: Arthur is right!.

Comment: @Arthur Damn, you're right, sorry.

Comment: This course I am doing marks it as incorrect. I used the same method for calculating the probability of 2 cards summing to 10 ($54/1326$) which worked out. But it fails for this one.

Comment: I can confirm your result. The probability drawing firstly a face card or a 10 and then a 11 is $\frac{16}{52}\cdot \frac{4}{51}$. Since we can draw the carde in reverse order we have to multiply it by $2$.

Comment: Are you sure that the drawing is without replacement of cards? Btw, what is brought forward as "correct answer"?

Comment: I see where I went wrong, I decided that 16*4 = 66, not 64...

Comment: @LiborZachoval Oh, sh.. happens.

Comment: I was on an error spree, at first I forgot to sum the kings, queens, jacks, and 10s, then I made a simple multiplication error.

Comment: @LiborZachoval  Such flaws are not unusual. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3306957/probability-statistics-probability-that-10-or-more-of-the-donors-are-rh-negati/3307470#3307470) the user just omit a $0$ of a figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. The probability is
$$
\frac{64}{1326}
$$
However, depending on how this is graded, they might expect an answer like
$$
\frac{32}{663},\quad4.8\%
$$
or something similar. The other possibility is that whoever marks your answer is just wrong. It happens from time to time. Or, as it turns out in the comments, $16\cdot 4$ can quickly become $66$ if you're being a bit too quick.

Answer (score 0):

Considering ordered hands,

- total hands: $52\cdot51$.
- winning hands: $4\cdot16+16\cdot4.$

Comment: Yes, and that gives the same answer.